# Parallel lines from a median and angle bisector in a triangle

Tags: geometry

> Suppose we have $\triangle DEF$ with $|\overline{DE}| < |\overline{DF}|$. Let the midpoint of $\overline{EF}$ be $G$, and let the bisector of $\angle D$ meet side $\overline{EF}$ at $H$. Let the foot of the perpendicular from $E$ to $\overline{DH}$ be $I$, and extend $\overline{EI}$ to meet median $\overline{DG}$ at $J$. Prove that $\overleftrightarrow{HJ}$ and $\overleftrightarrow{DE}$ are parallel.

I got this problem from a professor and I am not sure how to go about it. It LOOKS parallel, but I can't prove this. I am trying coordinates but it is not working out well.

[image: parallel from medians and bisector]

Comment: As @achillehui's diagram shows, the result is true even if $|\overline{DE}| > |\overline{DF}|$. What's really important is that $|\overline{DE}|\neq|\overline{DF}|$, so that $G$ and $H$ don't coincide. (BTW: I have a coordinate proof of the result, but am seeking a cleaner approach.)

Comment: Could I see the coordinate proof? I actually was attempting coordinates but it was not working out.

Comment: @Blue, oops, I draw the wrong figure. I didn't notice that b/c the statement also looks true in that case.

Comment: This question is very similar to [Problem 4 of the current round of the USAMTS](http://www.usamts.org/Tests/Problems_27_3.pdf) (an ongoing contest). The deadline for submitting solutions is 3PM EST on January 4th.

Comment: Deleting my answer until after the USAMTS deadline. (Note that the original problem statement is identical to the contest problem, except for the naming of points. I edited it into the current form without realizing the source.)

Comment: @Blue I didn't read this until just now. I guess there's not much that can be done, except post the solutions again later and hope that the USAMTS people find them here. According to Wikipedia, the competition is sponsored by the NSA, so I'm sure they'll find out: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/United_States_of_America_Mathematical_Talent_Search

Comment: @David: This happens from time to time. (The "Tetris" problem recently posted is also from the same contest.) I've flagged the question for moderator attention, so that the entire post might be temporarily closed as per site policy, but temporarily deleting our answers is appropriate in the meantime.

Comment: @Blue Too bad, I really enjoyed working on this question. I guess we should be suspicious whenever a problem has letters starting at D for no apparent reason.

Answer (score 2):

[image]

take mid point $M$ of $DE$,connect $IM$,cross $EF$ at $G_1$, sine $\triangle DIE$ is right triangle, $\implies \angle IME= 2\angle IDE=\angle FDE \implies IM // DF \implies G_1=G$

make $HJ' //DE$, cross $IM$ at $K \implies \dfrac{HG}{GE}=\dfrac{HK}{ME}=\dfrac{HJ}{DE}$,(it is trivial that $K$ is mid point of $HJ'$)

connect $DJ'$, cross $EF$ at $G_2 \implies \dfrac{HG_2}{G_2E}=\dfrac{HJ}{DE}=\dfrac{HG}{GE}  \\ \implies G_2=G \implies DG_2=DG  \\ \implies J'=J \implies HJ //DE $

it doesn't matter $EF < DE$.

QED.

Answer (score 1):

[image]

Here's a coordinate proof. Let the trangle's edge-lengths be $d$, $e$, $f$ in the usual arrangement, and assign these coordinates to the vertices:
$$D = (0,0) \qquad E = (f,0) \qquad F = e\,(\cos D, \sin D)$$
Midpoint $G$'s coordinates are easy:
$$G = \frac{1}{2}(E+F) = \left( \frac{f + e \cos D}{2}, \frac{e \sin D}{2} \right)$$
By the [Angle Bisector Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Angle_bisector_theorem), we know that $H$ is a point such that $e\,|\overline{HE}| = f\,|\overline{HF}|$, which allows us to write
$$H = \frac{1}{f+e}\left(\;e E + f F\;\right) = \frac{ef}{e+f}\left(\;1 + \cos D, \sin D \;\right)$$

Then we have
$$\begin{align}
\overleftrightarrow{EI}&:\quad x ( 1+ \cos D) + \sin D y = f ( 1 + \cos D) \\
\overleftrightarrow{DG}&:\quad e \sin D x = y ( f + e \cos D )
\end{align}$$
so that
$$J = \left(\frac{f (f + e \cos D)}{e + f}, \frac{e f \sin D}{e + f} \right)$$
which has the same $y$-coordinate as $H$ (but a distinct $x$-coordinate), so that $\overleftrightarrow{HJ}$ is parallel to the $x$-axis, and thus $\overleftrightarrow{DE}$. $\square$

---

**Notes**

- At no time does this argument assume $f > e$. We only require that $f \neq e$, so that $H$ and $J$ are distinct points (otherwise $\overleftrightarrow{HJ}$ is undefined).
- If we construct $H^\prime$ as the point where the *external* bisector at $D$ meets $\overleftrightarrow{EF}$, then we can construct companion points $I^\prime$ and $J^\prime$ as before, to get $\overleftrightarrow{H^\prime J^\prime}\parallel\overleftrightarrow{DE}$. The argument is just as above, except we replace $e$ with $-e$ in the definition of $H^\prime$ (and calculation of $J^\prime$). In this case, the requirement $f \neq e$ guarantees that $H^\prime$ is not a point at infinity.

Comment: What is the ratio IJ to JE in terms of points D,E,F

Comment: @KshitijSingh: I don't have time to revisit a three(!)-year-old problem right now, but the ratio you seek should be fairly straightforward to determine from the information I've given. All you need is to determine the coordinates of point $I$. You might take a look at the other two answers, which avoid coordinates and feature ratios.

Answer (score 0):

*Note. This solution has been revised to simplify part of the argument*.

This solution uses the fact that the cross-ratio of four points is invariant under central projection from one line to another.

Let $K$ be the reflection of $E$ with respect to line $DI$. Then triangle $DEK$ is isosceles, $I$ is the midpoint of $EK$, and $K$ is on $DF$ (since the angle at $D$ is bisected by $DI$). We have $K \ne F$ since $DK = DE \ne DF$, hence $H \ne J$.

Henceforth all ratios of lengths should be considered signed.

My first claim is that $\frac{IH}{ID} = \frac{GH}{GF}$. To see this, note that $G$ and $I$ are the midpoints on the sides $EF$ and $EK$ of triangle $EFK$. It follows that $GI$ is parallel to line $KF$, which is also $FD$. This proves the first claim.

My next claim is that $\frac{IJ}{IE} = \frac{GH}{GF}$. This will be enough since $\frac{IJ}{IE} = \frac{IH}{ID}$ implies that $HJ$ and $DE$ are parallel. To prove the claim, we project line $EF$ onto $EK$ centrally from $D$. The images of $E, G, H, F$ under the projection are $E, J, I, K$, respectively. Since cross-ratios are preserved, we have (bearing in mind that $G$ is the midpoint of $EF$ and $I$ the midpoint of $EK$):

$$\begin{align*}
\frac{KI}{KE} \div \frac{JI}{JE} &= \frac{FH}{FE} \div \frac{GH}{GE}, \\
\frac{1}{2}\frac{JE}{JI} &= \frac{1}{2} \frac{FH}{GH}.
\end{align*}
$$
The last claim follows easily from this and completes the proof.

Comment: The main thing to see here is that once $K$ (the reflection of $E$ with respect to $I$) is placed in the figure, all the other points can be determined in an affinely invariant way in terms of the triangle $DEK$ and the choice of a point $F$ on side $DK$. What I mean by this is that $G, H, I, J$ can be defined solely in terms of midpoints of segments and intersections of lines, and these constructions are invariant under affine transformations. From that point forward, $DEK$ can be replaced with any other convenient triangle. It becomes plausible that a purely projective proof is possible....

Comment: ...Alternatively, let $D= (0,0)$, $E=(1,0)$, $K = (0,1)$, $F = (0,c)$ and use coordinates. For the reasons stated, it makes no difference that the coordinate system is not rectangular, so long as $I$ is defined as the midpoint of $EK$.